# Find integral of a polar function $h(r,\theta)$ over a circle

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am studying for my math final and our prof gave us a review but without any solutions or hints. I don't really understand this problem so if anyone could help me out here I would appreciate it.

> Find the integral of the polar function $h(r, \theta) = r \cos(\theta) , r \ge 0$, over the circle $r = 2a\cos(\theta)$ .

Again I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume (perhaps incorrectly) that whoever asked the question really meant what they wrote, which is, to integrate over a *circle* (a curve) and not over the *interior* of the circle (a disc).  I would find the center and radius of the circle, starting by multiplying both sides of the equation of the circle by $r$, and eventually completing the square.  I'll assume $a > 0$.  I think the circle will have radius $a$ and center $(x,y)=(a,0)$.  Then parametrize the circle, using a letter other than $\theta$ as the angle, and you'll get something like $x(t)=a+a\cos(t),\ y(t)=a+a\sin(t),\ 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.  Note that your function $h(r,\theta) = r\cos(\theta) = x$.
Now find $\int_0^{2\pi} x(t)\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}\,dt$.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking an integral in polar coordinates takes the form:

$\int_{a}^{b}\int_{0}^{r(\theta)}f(r,\theta)rdrd\theta$

notice the function is being multiplied by the radius inside the integral.

You can use this as a standard formula and sub in the function you wish to integrate. Use your expression for $r(\theta)$ as the upper limit of the radial integration: Do not sub the expression for $r$ into the integrand, only in the upper limit! That is only an equation for the outer curve enclosing the area, it does not represent all $r$ values inside the entire area. For the integral on the inside you integrate with respect to $r$ and treat $\theta$ as a constant. Then you integrate that result with respect to $\theta$ to finish it off. For the angular limits you integrate from $0$ to $2\pi$ in order to go all the way round.

Comment: So would the integral then be: $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2acos\theta} rcos\theta rdrd\theta$ ??

Comment: Yeah that's it...

Comment: Jeez.. I am making a mess of this. No if you are integrating over a circle the upper limit should be $r=2a$ not $r=2acos(\theta)$ the result will be zero due to symmetry and this is supported graphically. But then I am confused by your expression for the "circle", it should have a constant radius that should not change as a function of $\theta$!? If you are integrating over an area enclosed by the curve $r=2a\cos(\theta))$ that is your upper limit but that is not a   "circle"... Have you possibly mixed up the words from 2 questions or am I being stupid?

Comment: The question I originally asked was copied word for word from our review sheet.

Comment: Yes, sorry I made a mistake here. That is a circle just not centred at the origin... :( ...and I have told you how to integrate over the disk (area) and not along the line described by the circle. I would suggest you accept Stefan Smith's answer below. I will not delete this just yet in case you wish to refer to the difference for some reason. Apologies...